# Controlling the order of controls being populated on a form in VB 2008

Tags: vb.net, datagrid, listbox, population

My form contains a datagrid and a checked listbox. The listbox is populated on the form_load event. There's a function called when the datagrid's SelectionChanged event is triggered that modifies the checkmarks in the listbox. It all works fine when I manually click on any item in the datagrid.

However, the very first time the form runs, the checkmarks are not affected, even though the first item in the datagrid appears selected. I discovered that this is because the actual listbox is not yet populated on the form at the time the very first SelectionChanged event is triggered. So when the function tries setting the checkboxes, it doesn't get anywhere, since it doesn't see any items in the listbox.

Somehow the datagrid is getting populated, even before the form_load event is triggered. I need the listbox to be populated before the datagrid is populated, but I have no idea how to control this.

Any ideas how to solve my dilemma?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve these problems (do something during formload, but after all controls were loaded) by using a timer.
it's disabled, with a time of 10 ms.
in formload as last action I enable it.
in the timer tick I disable the timer and execute the rest of the code.

So the timertick executes immediatly after the form has loaded.

Comment: I don't think I would go through all that it feels a bit like a cheat.  If you were going to do all that, then why not just create some sub like AfterLoadComplete() to call as the last line in the loading event?

Comment: I had to maintainprograms writteb by others, and I guarantee, that using a boolean like FormIsLoading to be able to write "If Loading then exit sub" is easy when you are testing a program, but hard to modify and add controls. I like my form clean, ready and then I start processing. No trick, no cheat, just divide things: layout from processing

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question at the end of my comment.  If your goal is to execute code immediately after the form has loaded... what is wrong with a Sub named anything you want called as the last line of the load? Rather than adding a timer that gives you a timer tick to do exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't answer your question directly, but perhaps after you load the list box you can call the  SelectionChanged sub in order to cause the behavior you want.  Rather than try to control the order.

Comment: This might work, but you can't call an event handler without passing in the right parameters. How do I create the 'sender As Object', 'e As System.EventArgs' parameters? Can I just create 2 new such variables and pass them along? I always thought those objects were special somehow.

Comment: If sender and e are unused in your sub like SelectionChanged(Nothing,Nothing).  Otherwise you would have to create the variables to represent the parameters and send them.  Using the datagrid control as the sender and creating the args and supplying any info you need. (usually I find nothing, nothing is sufficient)

Comment: Sorry to be more correct for the args you should send args.empty rather than nothing if you aren't using it.  And yeah sender and e aren't any more special than any other object.